# Javascript variable can't be overwritten after the first declaration

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that will refresh the page based on the number chosen:

```js
prodName="doesn't matter, not directly $.ajax related"

function searchProduct() {
  var prodName = $("#admin-search-product").val().trim();
  var pagenumb = 1;
  $(".page-item").click(function() {
    pagenumb = $(this).children('.page-link').attr('value');
  });
  alert(pagenumb);
  if (prodName == "") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin_search_product.php",
      data: {
        search_prod: 0,
      },
      success: function(respond) {
        $("#admin_content").html(respond).show();
        $("#admin-search-product").focus().val('').val(prodName);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin_search_product.php",
      data: {
        search_prod: 1,
        searchName: prodName,
        pagenumb: pagenumb
      },
      success: function(respond) {
        $("#admin_content").html(respond).show();
        $("#admin-search-product").focus().val('').val(prodName);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="admin-search-product">

<div class="page-item">
<input class="page-link">
</div>

<button onclick="searchProduct()">clickme</button>
```

Everything works well, except the problem is that the pagenumb variable stays on "1" even though the code "pagenumb = $(this).children('.page-link').attr('value');" can retrieve the value of the page clicked, tested with alert() function and it can return the value of "2" if put within the click function.

However if I test the alert() function outside the click function, it shows that the pagenumb variable stayed the same. I don't know why it doesnt want to change the received value even though I'm able to receive it.

Comment: The problem is ***when*** the new value gets assigned to the variable!

Comment: any code that depends on the value of your $.ajax call, will need to wait on the returned Promise of the $.ajax, or wait to execute until after your success callbacks are called

Comment: @user It’s not about AJAX, it’s about the click handler.

Comment: @deceze Oh, that's a problem with scope then, not asynchronicity.  Within the scope of the execution environment of the function it is set to 1 and never 2.  He just needs to put it outside the context of the function so its value is different after each successive function call.  That's not really an issue of asynchronicity at all, and reading all of that won't really help him?

Comment: @Lawlette J you just need to put pagenumb outside the function closure.  Within the scope of that function (directly) it is never changed to 2.  Only when it is outside the scope of that function, do successive calls to searchProduct update that variable in a shared context.

Comment: @deceze based on what you've pointed out, I'd like to politely recommend that this be reopened.  It's definitely _not_ a dupe of that topic linked.  I would reopen it directly, but I don't know how I feel about directly overriding a moderator's decision without communication.

Comment: @user120242 Thanks, it works! But its kinda off though, the pagenumb variable stayed as "1" on the first click, but then on the second click it only changed to "2".

Comment: @user It’s definitely about asynchronous execution. The click handler gets executed if and when the user clicks on the element. The rest of the code isn’t waiting for that.

Comment: @LawletteJ move your click handler outside your search function along with the pagenumb variable.  You should not be attaching a click handler after calling searchProduct.  You should be attaching it when your elements exist.  You're actually creating another click handler every time you try to search for a product, which is definitely not what you want to do.

Comment: @deceze I have to strongly respectfully disagree.  It is a scoping issue, and an issue of improperly attaching a click event.  This is not asynchronicity, and even if it is technically _almost_ kind of has some truth to it being related to order of execution and waiting, the article is entirely unhelpful to the OP's problem.  It is talking about subjects that have no relation to the problems with his code and with even 5 years of research would still not be helpful in directing him to a solution.

Comment: @deceze Simple gist of it is this: Tell me how reading that long article about asynchronous functions would help him realize his variable is in the wrong scope and his click handler shouldn't be attached when calling searchProduct()?  What does that have anything to do with asynchronous execution?  His code hasn't even gotten to the working point where asynchronous issues are a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the event handler **once** when the **page is ready**, *not every time you searchProducts()*.
You want the **change** event, *not click*.  `pagenumb` should be updated when the input's value changes.  Click will only try to update the value when you focus the input box, which is not what you want.

```js
prodName = "doesn't matter, not directly $.ajax related"

var pagenumb = 1;

// you should bind this event handler _once_ when the _page is ready_
// you want the change event, not click. update pagenumb whenever value _changes_
$(".page-item").change(function() {
  // coerce to number using + operator
  pagenumb = +$(this).children('.page-link').val();
});

function searchProduct() {
  var prodName = $("#admin-search-product").val().trim();

  alert(pagenumb);
  if (prodName == "") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin_search_product.php",
      data: {
        search_prod: 0,
      },
      success: function(respond) {
        $("#admin_content").html(respond).show();
        $("#admin-search-product").focus().val('').val(prodName);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin_search_product.php",
      data: {
        search_prod: 1,
        searchName: prodName,
        pagenumb: pagenumb
      },
      success: function(respond) {
        $("#admin_content").html(respond).show();
        $("#admin-search-product").focus().val('').val(prodName);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="admin-search-product">

<div class="page-item">
  <input class="page-link">
</div>

<button onclick="searchProduct()">clickme</button>
```